# Setting SO_RCVTIMEO socket option in python3

Tags: linux, sockets, python-3.x

I was wondering if `socket.setdefaulttimeout` set the `SO_RCVTIMEO` and `SO_SNDTIMEO` socket options, so I tried this:

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(0.1) # 100 milliseconds
c = socket.socket()
x = c.getsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVTIMEO, 16)
# I think SO_RCVTIMEO uses a struct of two 8 byte ints,
# the first being an amount of time in second and the
# second an amount of time in milliseconds. So, I expect
# x[8:] to be a little endian 8-byte int equal to 100.
print(x)
# this outputs a 16 bytes of 0.
```

So python's `socket.setdefaulttimeout` doesn't work like I expect. So, I tried setting the `SO_RCVTIMEO` myself:

```
import socket
c = socket.socket()
c.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVTIMEO, (0).to_bytes(8, 'little') + (100).to_bytes(8, 'little'))
print(c.getsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVTIMEO, 16))
# The first 8 bytes are 0 as expected, but the last eight bytes as an int
# is 4000, and not 100!
```

Does anyone know why the value returned in `getsockopt` is different from the value I set with `setsockopt`? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.1, and I looked at the man page for sockets in section 7, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I know that when you set `SO_RCVBUF`, the OS doubles the size you specify. Is something similar going on here? I don't want my sockets to block for 4 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I wrote a little C script to print the size of a timeval struct and verify that it is 16 bytes long:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int
main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  printf("size of struct timeval: %d\n", sizeof(struct timeval));
  return 0;
}
```

Which prints `size of struct timeval: 16`. So I googled `struct timeval` and found out that the members are an amount of seconds, and an amount of **micro**seconds, not milliseconds. That means I was trying to set my timeout to 100 microsecond, and the OS's minimum timeout is 4 milliseconds. Whoops! To check this is correct, I worte this python3 script:

```
import socket
c = socket.socket()
### this time use 100,000 microseconds (100 milliseconds)
c.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVTIMEO, (8*b'\x00')+(100000).to_bytes(8, 'little'))
x = c.getsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVTIMEO, 16)
print('socket timeout seconds:', int.from_bytes(x[:8], 'little'))
print('socket timeout microseconds:', int.from_bytes(x[8:], 'little'))
### OUTPUT
# socket timeout seconds: 0
# socket timeout microseconds: 100000
```